# header() download corrupted file

Tags: php, download

Why this code doesn't work, the url is a sound file:

```
header("Location: http://biencaleta.com/musica/Billboard-70s/Grupos/Billboard%201970.ca/Simon Y Garfunkel - Bridge Over Trubled.msa");
```

The browser(chrome) just play it instead of downloading it, but it does work with this `http://23.250.9.10/~caletaco/Alkilados - Mona Lisa.msa` I tried also with:

```
$file='http://biencaleta.com/musica/Billboard-70s/Grupos/Billboard%201970.ca/Simon Y Garfunkel - Bridge Over Trubled.msa';
$basename = basename($file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $basename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

set_time_limit(0);
readfile($file);
```

But it download a corrupted file.
Thanks

Comment: I have a similar but different issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946612/php-download-script-outputs-corrupted-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By leaving the spaces in place, you are requesting an invalid URL. Your browser takes care of it for you, but you'll have to do the leg work in PHP.

Starting with the filename:

```
$url="http://biencaleta.com/musica/Billboard-70s/Grupos/Billboard 1970.ca/Simon Y Garfunkel - Bridge Over Trubled.msa";
```

... we'll use `explode` on it to break the URL into the various :

```
$url= explode('/', $url);
```

Now we have an array:

```
var_dump($url);
/*
array (size=8)
  0 => string 'http:' (length=5)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string 'biencaleta.com' (length=14)
  3 => string 'musica' (length=6)
  4 => string 'Billboard-70s' (length=13)
  5 => string 'Grupos' (length=6)
  6 => string 'Billboard 1970.ca' (length=17)
  7 => string 'Simon Y Garfunkel - Bridge Over Trubled.msa' (length=43)
 */
```

Within that array, you have a bunch of parts that need to be URL encoded. PHP has a function for that, called `rawurlencode`. You can't simply throw the entire URL at the function, though, because it will encode the `http://` part, which we don't want.

We'll save the protocol, and get rid of that empty item (it came from the "//" part of the URL):

```
$protocol = array_shift($url); // save this
array_shift($url);             // throw this out
```

Now, you can safely encode the rest:

```
foreach ($url as &$part)
    $part = rawurlencode($part);
```

... and put it all back together

```
$url = $protocol.'//'.implode('/', $url);
```

Compare the now-encoded URL against the original:

```
 enc: http://biencaleta.com/musica/Billboard-70s/Grupos/Billboard%201970.ca/Simon%20Y%20Garfunkel%20-%20Bridge%20Over%20Trubled.msa
orig: http://biencaleta.com/musica/Billboard-70s/Grupos/Billboard 1970.ca/Simon Y Garfunkel - Bridge Over Trubled.msa
```

... looking good. Now we can grab the contents and set the download:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$cleanName.'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
die($contents);
```

You may notice the `$cleanName` variable in there... what's that? Before the string gets encoded and messy-looking, you can grab the `basename` -- right **before** you explode it. Putting it all together:

```
$url = "http://biencaleta.com/musica/Billboard-70s/Grupos/Billboard 1970.ca/Simon Y Garfunkel - Bridge Over Trubled.msa";
$cleanName = basename($url);
$url = explode('/', $url);

$protocol = array_shift($url);
array_shift($url);

foreach ($url as &$part)
    $part = rawurlencode($part);
$url = $protocol.'//'.implode('/', $url);

$contents = file_get_contents($url);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$cleanName.'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
die($contents);
```

**Documentation**

- `explode` - http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php
- `rawurlencode` - http://php.net/manual/function.rawurlencode.php
- `implode` - http://php.net/manual/function.implode.php
- `basename` - http://php.net/manual/function.basename.php
- `file_get_contents` - http://php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: you gave sense to my life, thanks. But what about if i just replace the white space with %20

Comment: @user2495207 You could do that, but what about any other invalid character? It is bound to come up, especially when working with music. You have a lot of variables in artist names and song titles. If you plan on dealing with a lot of these over time and you don't prepare for any foreseeable issue, you have a "time bomb" in your code. Bugs come from typos, or edge cases (unusual circumstances) we fail to predict. Bad code comes (in part) from ignoring highly predictable problems.