# Php download script outputs corrupted file

Tags: php, download, http-headers

I was building a file download Class for my CMS in PHP, at a time I noticed it outputs files in a different Encoding format. I tried with readfile, file_get_contents,fread but all seem to be doing the same thing. It"s like something that has to do with output buffering.

An example image file in png format I downloaded using the script seems to work after changing the Encoding using notepad++ from UTF to ASCII

These are the steps i've taken so far:

```
$mime = http::get_file_mime();
header('Pragma: public');   
header('Expires: 0');       
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Encoding: chunked');
header('Connection: closed');
@readfile($this->file);
```

I did fread:

```
$file = fopen($this->file,'r');
$read = fread($file,filesize($this->file));
print($read);
```

I did file_get_contents();

```
$read = file_get_contents($this->file);
print($read);
```

All of these steps sends the file to the download dialog. But it doesnt output the file as it is. And this affects any file i try to download with the script.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: The funny thing is that the downloaded file begins to work after changing the Encoding to ANSI

Answer (score 1):

Try running an `ob_start()` as the first thing in your script, write stuff, edit your headers and then `ob_flush()` and `ob_clean()` whenever you want your content to be sent to the user's browser.

This is worked for me..

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: What should be in the header  Ajay?

Comment: try changing this...
`header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive'); OR header('Connection: close');`

Comment: Did you added `ob_start()`,`ob_clean()` and `ob_flush()` ??

Comment: I did that earlier. Meanwhile, at the backend of my CMS, the same download class works perfectly.

Comment: okey i had a same problem that had been fixed by ob_start() and other functions.
Did you compare that both file might be you are missing something here.

Comment: Try adding this header `header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `Content-Disposition` header. This header is not really part of the HTTP protocol, see [RFC 2616, 15.5 Content-Disposition Issues](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-15.5)

> Content-Disposition is not part of
> the HTTP standard, but since it is widely implemented, we are
> documenting its use and risks for implementors.

And later in section [19.5.1 Content-Disposition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.5.1)

> The Content-Disposition response-header field has been proposed as a
> means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user
> requests that the content is saved to a file.
> ...
> An example is

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

> If this header is used in a response with the application/octet-
> stream content-type, the implied suggestion is that the user agent
> should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response
> as...' dialog.

Leaving out this header shows the contents of the sent file.

*I have tested this with Firefox only, so other web browsers might behave different.*

Comment: Ajay i just tried that. And i tested it with an image file. The downloaded image cannot be viewed.

Comment: @WebICTByLeo You might want to move this comment to Ajay's answer.

Comment: Is it something with the output buffer ?

Comment: No, this is not a buffer issue. As I already wrote, removing the `Content-Disposition` header displays the contents of the file, instead of downloading it.

Comment: Thank you for that Olaf. But like I stated earlier, the same php Class works perfectly in the backend. My CMS has both frontend and backend and the same script handles file download in both

Comment: Okay. This seems like a buffer issue. I removed the Content-Disposition as you directed. Now the image isnt displaying because it's not valid.